# MySQL Decimal to 5 places

Tags: mysql

I'm kinda new to MySQL and am currently training.

I've been given a table to create and have most of it done but I'm stuck on the following:

**To the table `Shop` add column name `Charge` as a decimal to 5 places.**

I'm unsure what "decimal to 5 places" means.

So I'm using `ALTER` to add this column:

```
ALTER table Shop ADD column Charge DECIMAL(5,0)
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D) where:

- M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of
  1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
- D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

So you could use something like DECIMAL(10,5).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice and the links.